# Working with multiple submit buttons

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, submit

I am currently running through an issue when i go to a page and click on one of my buttons I get a page cannot be displayed error message. I realized is that because i have multiple submit buttons and when i click on a button it doesn't know what to fire up. Here is the button that i currently have:

```
<button class="glossyBtn" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="@Html.Encode(Kids.Resources.Message.Ok)">
                            <img alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right:1px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/tick.png")" />
                        <span style="vertical-align: middle">Ok</span> 
                            </button>
```

This is what i have in my .cshtml page:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Invoice"))
        {
            <fieldset id="contentView">
                <div class="row">

                    @Html.Raw(Html.DatePickerEnable())
                    <fieldset>

                        <span>@Kids.Resources.Entities.Billing.BillingStatus</span> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BillingStatuses)
                        <br />
                    <div style="float:left; width:320px">
                        <span>Begin Date</span> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BeginDate) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m
                    => m.BeginDate)
                        <span>End Date</span> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndDate) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m
                    => m.EndDate)
                     <div style="background-color: white;" class="bubble">@Html.ValidationSummary(true, Message.ValidationErrorSummary, new { @class = "error" })</div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="glossyBtn" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="@Html.Encode(Kids.Resources.Message.Ok)">
                            <img alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right:1px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/tick.png")" />
                        <span style="vertical-align: middle">Ok</span> 
                            </button>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>

@if (Model.Invoices != null)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        @Html.Grid(Model.Invoices).Attributes(id => "Invoices").Columns(column =>
                                        {
                                            column.For(i => i.CanAddItems ? string.Format(
                                                "<a class='noStyle' href='{0}' title='Edit'><img src='{1}'/></a>",
                                                Url.Action("Prepare", "Invoice", new { invoiceId = i.InvoiceId }),
                                                Url.Content("~/Content/images/pencilEdit.png")) : string.Empty).Sortable(false).Encode(false);
                                            column.For(i => i.CanPay ? string.Format(
                                                "<a class='noStyle' href='{0}' title='Pay'><img class='pic' src='{1}'/></a>",
                                                Url.Action("Pay", "Invoice", new { invoiceId = i.InvoiceId }),
                                                Url.Content("~/Content/images/moneySign.png")) : string.Empty).Sortable(false).Encode(false);
                                            column.For(i => i.CanVoid ? string.Format(
                                                "<a class='noStyle' href='{0}' title='Void'><img class='pic' src='{1}'/></a>",
                                                Url.Action("Void", "Invoice", new { invoiceId = i.InvoiceId }),
                                                Url.Content("~/Content/images/newVoid.png")) : string.Empty).Sortable(false).Encode(false);
                                            if (Kids.Common.KidsSettings.Settings.SubmissionInvoice)
                                            {
                                                column.For(i => i.CanSubmit ? string.Format(
                                                "<a class='noStyle' href='{0}' title='{2}'><img class='pic' src='{1}'/></a>",
                                                Url.Action("Files", "PaymentVoucherFile", new { invoiceId = i.InvoiceId }),
                                                Url.Content("~/Content/images/newVoucher.png"), Kids.Resources.Ocr.PaymentVoucherFile) : string.Empty).Sortable(false).Encode(false);
                                            }
                                        }).Empty(string.Format("No {0}", Kids.Resources.Entities.Billing.Invoices)).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
                        <p />
```

I looked throughout the site and what i found seemed like a little too much work. Is there something simple that i can do on the same page like javascript or something rather than making changes to two or three files.

The Prepare - Pay - Void are also forms which contain the same structure with same submit buttons.

Comment: you need to provide more code. What does the surrounding <form> tag looks like? What does the other submit button look like?

Comment: I don't know much about C# or ASP.net, but usually a submit button submits an HTML `<form>`, which has an `action` attribute that determines where the data is submitted to. The submit button does not determine that.

Comment: Are you having multiple forms, not only multiple submit buttons?

Comment: @Rickard added more - the submit buttons are the same all ok but with different forms which end up saving or filtering other information.

Comment: @DusanRadojevic yes i also have multiple forms - I added above more code.

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about.  You only have 1 Html.BeginForm call anywhere in that view, and you have no other html form tags instantiated.  You only have 1 submit button.  The others are Anchor tags

Comment: I don't think your problem is in the view. Does your Invoice controller have a post action called Manage?

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's hitting the action defined in your form tag?  The problem may be with the view that the "Manage" action is returning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many submit buttons for different forms then in javascript use something like this:

var form = $(document.forms['formName']) // or use indexes like $(document.forms[0]

then form.submit(); those buttons will require onclick actions and type='button'

Hope this helps